# How to resolve the following error shown while trying to build the code for Azure DevOps on Visual Studio 2022 on Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, .net-framework-version, windows-server-2019, visual-studio-2022

**##[error]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at...**

Comment: Have tried installing .NET Framework version 4.5, 4.8, 5.0 and even 6.0 but the same error is displayed every time

Comment: any solution you got?

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to upgrade any project targeting .Net Framework 4.5 to 4.7.2 and then building on Visual Studio 2019 instead of 2022, same Win Server 2019

Comment: this worked for me too, running windows server 2022 and installed vs build tools 2019

Answer (score 1):

Changing from

```
vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

to

```
vmImage: 'windows-2019'
```

worked for me. It used to work earlier because 2019 was latest, now the latest is 2022 and there is issue with that.

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/5055

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved by downgrading from Visual Studio 2022 to Visual Studio 2014. I uninstalled Visual Studio 2022 and installed Visual Studio 2014, and the rest fell in place. My installation is now up and running.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the VSBuild@1 [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) and use an old version of Visual Studio, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 but I'm not sure if it's the only one that works. I also set my vmImage pool with windows-2019.